# What is this supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, geometry

For any $10$ points in the unit circle, what is the value of the supremum of
the sum of the pairwise distances between the $10$ points, in which the supremum is taken over all configurations of 10 points?

Comment: Thanks for any helpful answers!

Comment: Could you add some more details? How have you tried to solve this problem at the moment?

Comment: @KeeranBrabazon: Yes, I have tried my best, but don't know how to solve it. Let me know if you know how to. Thanks.

Comment: Supremum isn't usually used in this context, it sounds like you are asking for the maximum possible pairwise distance sum, over all possible choices of 10 points.

Comment: Your question is phrased strangely.  You say you're _given_ a set of ten points.  That suggests the set of ten points is to remain fixed while we seek the answer.  But "what is the value of the supremum of the sum of the pairwise distances between the ten points?" sounds as if we are to find the best set of ten points, rather than work with a fixed given set of ten points.

Comment: Could you solve it, if it were three points? Four? I'm not sure this kind of thinking leads to the finish line this time, but it's a natural thing to try.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I have changed it to "for". I mean the supremum is taken over all configurations of $10$ points.

Comment: The phrasing could still bear improvement.  "For any ten points" could reasonably be construed as "Find a separate solution for each possible set of ten points".  But I don't think that's what's intended.  I might have said "Among all sets of ten points in the unit circle, what is the value of the supremum of the sum of the pairwise distances between them?".

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe you have to arrange the 10 points in a regular 10-gon.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think you're right; there is a solution where all points are on the boundary of the unit disc per my answer, and I think under this restriction that the optimal solution will indeed have all points as vertices on an inscribed 10-gon.

Comment: It is easy to prove that the regular 10-gon is a "local maximum" in the narrow sense that if we fix positions of 9 of the vertices of a regular 10-gon, then the last point must complete the regular 10-gon to maximize the sum. I don't see how to complete this kind of thinking to a solution though.

Comment: I wonder if symmetry can help, as in the solution is 'rotation' and permutation invariant?

Comment: Does someone solved it for 3 points?

Comment: Yes. I can do it for 3 or 4 points.

Answer (score 1):

(take [$\tau$](http://tauday.com/)$=2\pi$)

I feel like your question could be better explained, but it is an interesting question nonetheless (if I got it right). If the points can be anywhere without sequence, then five of them shall have coordinates such as $(\sin\frac\tau4;\cos\frac\tau4)=(0;1)$ and other five $(1;0)$, yielding a sum of $10$, 5 diameters, because the diameter is the biggest possible chord. In general, for $n$ points in the unit circle, the biggest sum of distances between them one can get is $2(n-1)$.

If they are in order (clock or counter-clockwise), then we can't jump like that, and in that case, if we stretch one chord too much, the others will be smaller. So the biggest will be the most similar to the circumference, a regular decagon. "I have a proof of this, which this page is to narrow to contain." `:D` Actually I don't, but am trying to find one (generally for all $n$, not just for the decagon, for which a proof could be found by brute force). Call it a conjecture for now.

In a regular decagon (inscribed in the unit circle), the angles from each point to the center (as compared to the positive part of the $Ox$ axis counter-clockwise) will be $+\frac\tau{10}$ each point, with the first at $0$ (for simplicity). Let's call the first point $A=(\sin0;\cos0)=(0;1)$. For an inscribed $n$-agon (having therefore $n$ points), each point in the biggest sum in counter-clockwise order shall be:

$$
P_i=\left(\sin\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right);\cos\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\right)
$$

It doesn't matter whether $i$ is the $0$-based index of points, until $n-1$, or a $1$-based index until $n$, as $\sin0=\sin\tau$, but as $A$ is the first point and on the $Ox$ axis, we'll have to go for the first. Note $\forall a\in \mathbb N_0, P_i=P_{i+an}$, because of the $\tau$ periodicity of the sine and cosine.

The distance between two points $A$ and $B$ is $\sqrt{(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2}$, by the Pythagorean theorem. So their sum will be:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\sqrt{
\left(
\sin\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)\right)^2
+\left(
\cos\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)\right)^2
}=\\=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\sqrt{2
-2\sin\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\sin\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)
-2\cos\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\cos\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)}
=\\=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(
\sqrt2\sqrt{1
-\sin\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\sin\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)
-\cos\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\cos\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)}\right)
=\\=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(
\sqrt2\sqrt{1
+\cos\left(\frac{\tau(2i+1)}n\right)
-2\cos\left(\frac{\tau i}n\right)\cos\left(\frac{\tau(i+1)}n\right)
}\right)
$$

(note $P_0=P_n$, as generalized above; and remember the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) plus some [other properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) I just learned about)

Applying to $n=10$ (thank God Wolfram Alpha understands $\LaTeX$, I just used `2*pi` for `\tau`!) I got two different default exact results with the same approximation (I feel it works because the result is very close to $\tau=6,28...$. For those interested, I wasn't sure the trick I used to remove the sines worked so I tried both [before](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B9%7D%5Cleft%28+%5Csqrt2%5Csqrt%7B1+-%5Csin%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a+i%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29%5Csin%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a%28i%2B1%29%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29+-%5Ccos%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a+i%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29%5Ccos%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a%28i%2B1%29%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29%7D+%5Cright%29) and [after](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B9%7D%5Cleft%28+%5Csqrt2%5Csqrt%7B1+%2B%5Ccos%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bpi%2a2%2a%282i%2B1%29%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29+-2%5Ccos%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a+i%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29%5Ccos%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%2api%2a%28i%2B1%29%7D%7B10%7D%5Cright%29+%7D%5Cright%29). I digress away from the answer though, which is:

$$
5\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5}=\sqrt5+4\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5}-1=5\sqrt5-5\approx6,18
$$

I hope this is the answer you were looking for, I didn't use calculus though. I think it should be used (at least the concept of limits) to prove that conjecture, and I will add it later.

Comment: cant decide whether to upvote or downvote because of $\tau$

Comment: @enthdegree, come on $\tau$ is way better than $\pi$! Plus, most Maths guys in YouTube prefer it! `:P` BTW, do you think this was the answer the OP was hoping for? I was initially a bit confused by his question.